Can the temperature around a thermal cube exceed 95 degrees?
The Thermal Cube says:

This 3-inch cube of solid brimstone generates enough dry heat to keep
the temperature within 15 feet of it at 95 degrees Fahrenheit (35
degrees Celsius).

Does that mean the temperature within 15 ft of the cube also will not exceed 95 degrees Fahrenheit?

Hi, are you thinking about whether the Thermal Cube could potentially work as a  potential "coolant" for an area where the environment's temperature around it is much higher than 95? ...say in a desert at midday?

Yes, precisely.

Spells, and by extension magic items, do what the description says and nothing more. Beyond that, the rules are read in idiomatic English.
If the ambient temperature is below 95 degrees, the cube will generate enough heat to raise the temperature to 95 degrees in the area of effect.  There is no mention of a temperature gradient, and the effect is magic; there is no need to assume the temperature is 95 at the outer edges and hotter in the interior.
If the ambient temperature is above 95 degrees, well, then, it stays there.  Nothing in the description says it will generate heat under those circumstance.  Nothing in the description says it will remove heat under those circumstances.

FWIW it says "keep" not raise to - if we're using idiomatic English that means it won't go higher either.

@aslum I've never heard of an idiomatic usage of "generates enough dry heat" that means "cool down".

@aslum You have to read the whole sentence, though, not just individual words.  There is no idiomatic reading that links the generation of heat to a lowering of temperature.  There just is not.

Another way to explain this is that "keep the temperature at 95 degrees" is not the effect of the cube. The cube's only effect is "generates dry heat", and the 95 degrees is a descriptor to explain how much heat the cube generates.

So then does it do nothing if the temp isn't already 95? It says keep at not raise to. What if you put the cube in water? It says it generates dry heat, so does that man it can't heat liquids? The whole thing is kind of nonsensical at it's heart.

@aslum It's idiomatically clear.

@Novak If that was true we'd all be in agreement.

Sometimes, I really wish I could downvote comments.

The only effect of the cube is to generate dry heat
It's tempting to interpret the description as saying that the cube keeps the temperature at 95 degrees regardless of whether the surrounding ambient temperature is warmer or cooler, but reading carefully, the description doesn't actually say that. The only effect described for the cube is that it "generates [...] dry heat". The phrase "enough [...] to keep the temperature within 15 feet of it at 95 degrees Fahrenheit" is not an effect of the cube. It is just a descriptor of exactly how much heat the cube produces, which doesn't change the fact that only only effect described is heat generation. By definition, adding heat to a system can only increase its temperature, so the cube cannot cool its surroundings, because it only generates heat.

Another effect implied, if not described, is that the cube operates as a thermometer with a useful range from absolute zero to 95F.  It must be capable of varying its heat output, since the energy needed to maintain 95F against a 94F ambient is significantly less than at, say, 10F ambient.  The cube's output level should allow a careful observer to infer the current ambient temperature.

@aroth My interpretation is that the 95 degrees thing, as well as the uniform temperature anywhere within 15 feet, are just a simplification of the actual physics involved in order to make it practical to determine the effect of the item in actual play.

No, because D&D is not physics
You might intuitively imagine that this is a very hot cube that radiates heat in order to warm the air around it, but that's because that's how that would work in our world. It doesn't work that way in D&D (as evidenced by the fact that the cube sets the temperature in the entire 15 foot area to the same temperature, rather than a gradient, and does not affect the area outside it)
This cube does not radiate heat, it generates it, that is, creates it. Don't think of this as 'heat energy' that is added to the ambient heat energy. Conservation of energy doesn't exist in D&D. Just like Twilight Sanctuary replaces whatever the lighting in a 15 foot area is with 'dim light', this cube 'generates' dry heat.
Twilight Sanctuary fills a 30 foot area with 'dim light'.1
This cube fills a 15 foot radius with '95 degree dry heat'.
It's not additive, it's not subtractive. It simply is. Because magic.

The temperature might have to exceed 95 degrees
While the cube is a magic item, the magical function of it is that it generates dry heat (as worded in its description). How much heat? Enough to keep the temperature within 15 feet of it at 95 degrees Fahrenheit. Notably, it does not magically keep the temperature, no, it only magically generates heat toward that purpose.
First of all, by generating heat it does not seem possible to keep the temperature down to 95.
Second of all, to make sure the temperature is achieved throughout the whole 15 feet radius in a windy, frosty climate, the heat output would have to be considerable! Therefore temperatures close to cube's surface would have to be quite a bit higher than that for the more distant parts to be sufficiently heated.
Absurdly, for it to work in such arctic conditions, the heat it generates would probably be unbearable to a living creature.

surprisingly it does not tell so, so it doesn't.

@Trish But it literally does tell. The texts says what it does. It produces heat. The text even says how much heat it produces. The "there are no hidden rules" principle is not supposed to squash any and all physical implications. Would Boots of False Tracks not protect you from an annoyingly cold floor in the morning? Would Grease be colorless? The spell description does not say it has color. Is a normal non-magical roaring bonfire (or stove, or whatever) not unbearable to sit close to?

I think you are forgetting about the magic element here. It's not radiating heat, it's magically heating. It may not even be warm to the touch.

The whole point of my (wantonly pedantic, as any RAW readings here must be) answer is, that the magical element is not keeping the temperature but generating heat. After the heat is generated, there is nothing else magical going on, since magic items do only what they say they do.  I.e. it is in fact not magically heating. Compare Leo's Tiny Hut: "The atmosphere inside the space is comfortable and dry, regardless of the weather outside." The spell magically creates comfy atmosphere. The cube? Only magically generates heat. How does it do it? Magic. How does the heat behave? As any heat.

My point is: the item does not tell it is a) hot to the touch b) has a temperature gradient zone or c) that thermodynamics apply at all! In a Hard-Sci-Fi world, yes, your reasoning would apply, but we're dealing with magic that just... makes it so

@Trish I do get that and I am not trying to go simulationist here, but I would appreciate if you could address where are the limits of this approach from your perspective with the Grease, the Boots and the common bonfire in my comment above.

@J.E you did go simulationist the moment you said "the heat output would have to be considerable!" - That is not in the spell, and not even implied. Boots are implied to still be boots. The effect of Grease is implied to create a slippery substance of some thing. But this spell does not imply at any moment that any temperature is higher than 95, when in fact, it says otherwise.

The rules don't say where the heat is generated; perhaps it generates the heat uniformly across the 15 foot cube (or in whatever distribution is needed). In that interpretation there is no "hot spot" at the center where the brimstone is.

@DanielWagner - Indeed, it is a magic item that generates enough heat throughout a volume to compensate for any heat loss at the edges (or wherever), and it does it as fast as you like. There's every suggestion that no heat is directly generated in the cube.

Aside from the idiomatic reading of the item's effect, the item is clearly meant as a major convenience and mitigation against the typical temperatures found in Icewind Dale.  It is clearly not meant as something that is unbearable to living creatures when in use.

@J.E "How does it do it? Magic. How does the heat behave? As any heat." - Yes, but the text doesn't say where the heat is generated.  You've assumed it happens within the cube, but nothing says the magic cube needs to radiate the thermal energy from its surface.  Perhaps it just magically inserts it directly into the air.  All the air within 15 feet, at exactly the right amount to get 95F.  In which case the surface of the cube might be cold, warm, or imperceptibly exactly 95F at all times.
